# Can specific text in a textbox trigger a jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working an MVC ASP.Net application where the user needs to fill out a form. There is a text box where the user must enter how long they've worked at their current employment. If the user enters less than three years, then I need a section of the form for their previous employment to pop up. When the page loads, this section is hidden with jQuery.

The user can enter a number between 0 and 99 or else an error is triggered. For this reason, I can't really use a dropdown menu to do this; it makes more sense for the user to enter the value.

Can a specific value entered into a textbox trigger a jQuery event to happen? I've been trying to find a solution to my problem, and my lack of experience with jQuery is really affecting my ability to make it work. I could really use some guidance because, logically, this code makes sense in my head and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

MVC Model

```
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 99)]
    [Display(Name = "Number of Years at Current Employer")]
    public int Buy1YearsAtEmployer { get; set; }
```

HTML/Razor Syntax:

```
  <div class="form-group required col-md-4">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Buy1YearsAtEmployer, new { @class = "control-label" })
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Buy1YearsAtEmployer, new { id = "applicantYearsAtCurrentEmployer", @Value = "", @class = "form-control" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Buy1YearsAtEmployer, "Please enter a valid number of years", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>


 <div class="container" id="applicantPreviousWork">
      <h4>Your Previous Employment</h4>
      <!--More code--!>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```
    $('#applicantYearsAtCurrentEmployer').focusout(function () {
    if ($(Buy1YearsAtEmployer).val() <= 3) {
        $('#applicantPreviousWork').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#applicantPreviousWork').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: this: `$(Buy1YearsAtEmployer)` should be `$('#applicantYearsAtCurrentEmployer')` or `$(this)` since the callback has the execution context of the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine. Change `Buy1YearsAtEmployer` to `this`. [See my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7n965dk8/2/)

```
<input id="applicantYearsAtCurrentEmployer">

<div id="applicantPreviousWork" style="display:none;">
Years worked...
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
 $('#applicantYearsAtCurrentEmployer').focusout(function () {
    if ( $(this).val() <= 3) {
        $('#applicantPreviousWork').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#applicantPreviousWork').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery change function on textbox to capture the value. Then, open your popup according to the value. For input text field, the change event is fired when the value changes and text field loses focus.

https://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#applicantYearsAtCurrentEmployer').change(function() {
  var currVal = $(this).val();
 //Now put your logic here.
});});
```